# Return Data of two tables using mysql join as one java Object in Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

CPT Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CPT")
public class CPTCodeset {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String desc;
//getters and setters
}
```

CPT Procedures Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cptprocedures")
public class CPTProcedures {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private int Id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ProcedureId")
    private Procedure procedure;
    @Transient
    private int procedureId;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CPTCodeSet")
    private CPTCodeset cpt;
    @Transient
    private int cptCodeSet;
//getters and setters
}
```

CPTRepository

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT cp.ProcedureId,c.Code,c.Description FROM cptprocedures cp JOIN CPT c ON cp.CPTCodeSet = c.Id where c.Description like \"%ane\";")
List<CPTCodeset> findBySearch(@Param("searchString") String searchString);
```

This Query Returning Data is what I want. But how can I map this data into a single object where as it includes 2 tables.

How can I do it by using `@Entity` without creating a table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show what you have attempted so far? Also it would be a good idea to show the Entity you are trying to map to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Query("SELECT new com.dto.ProduceCPT(cp.ProcedureId, c.Code, c.Description) FROM cptprocedures cp JOIN CPT c ON cp.CPTCodeSet = c.Id where c.Description like \"%ane\" ")
List< ProduceCPT> fetchProduceCPT();
```

Comment: So this ProduceCPT is acts like a Wrapper class right

Comment: ProduceCPT is a wrapper class

Comment: be sure of your constructor
plz refer to this link:
https://smarterco.de/spring-data-jpa-query-result-to-dto/

Comment: The Description is TEXT type in mySql Data Table

Comment: I have created Parameterized constructor but then also it is saying same ```cptprocedures not mapped```

Comment: Thanks this works. But would have been better if code was explained more. anyways. For other commers: The `ProduceCPT` DTO(Data Transaction Object) acts as the wrapper of the parameters from various of your entity attributes so you can return in a list of those combination of entities. The DTO needs to have a constructor and getters so that it can return those values. Now the DTO also helps in reducing the # of calls your service methods will make in getting data from the DB or server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong if you are using JPA and still thinking in terms of tables first. The whole point of JPA is to have SQL generated from objects so you can pretend that the relational model doesn't exist

For this example you can use a [projection interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

That can solve your problem, you doing your projection, and later set the information into a WrapperObject. But you cant do a Wrapper in your JPARepository, if that wrapper doesn't exists in your Database.

Comment: Yeah Thats what i'm thinking but i didn't getting idea about how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `desc` field name. It’s better not to use `JPA` reserved words

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CPT")
public class CPTCodeset {
    //fields

    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description; 

    //getters and setters
}
```

To get query result as `List<Object[]>`

```
@Query("select cp.procedure.id, c.code, c.description "
         + "from CPTProcedures cp join cp.cpt c "
         + "where c.description like :searchString")
List<Object[]> findBySearch(@Param("searchString") String searchString);
```

or create `DTO` class with appropriate constructor `SearchResultDto(int, String, String)` and use this

```
@Query("select new yourproject.dto.SearchResultDto(cp.procedure.id, c.code, c.description) "
         + "from CPTProcedures cp join cp.cpt c "
         + "where c.description like :searchString")
List<SearchResultDto> findBySearch(@Param("searchString") String searchString);
```

Repository usage:

```
// description contains searchString  
List<SearchResultDto> dtos1 = repository.findBySearch("%" + searchString + "%");

// description start with searchString
List<SearchResultDto> dtos2 = repository.findBySearch("%" + searchString); 

// description end with searchString
List<SearchResultDto> dtos3 = repository.findBySearch(searchString + "%");
```

Comment: I tried with DTO but is showing error like ```cptprocedures is not mapped```